# FOSRestBundle: How to set an array to an URL in my Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, symfony, url

I have my RestBundle in Symfony and I want to send an array in my api-url-call:

```
@Annotations\QueryParam(
     *   name = "codes",
     *   array = true,
     *   nullable = false,
     * )
```

But when i put an url-encoded array in my link for example:

```
...0%5BcodeId%5D=443&0%5Bcode%5D=AAA222&1%5BcodeId%5D=443&1%5Bcode%5D=BBB222&2%5BcodeId%5D=443&2%5Bcode%5D=ABC123
```

It says that there is an array instead of as string. But how do I set an array into a link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    "...%5BcodeId%5D%5B0%5D=443&%5Bcode%5D%5B0%5D=AAA222&%5BcodeId%5D%5B1%5D=443&%5Bcode%5D%5B1%5D=BBB222&%5BcodeId%5D%5B2%5D=443&%5Bcode%5D%5B2%5D=ABC123"
```

Decoded:

```
...[codeId][0]=443&[code][0]=AAA222&[codeId][1]=443&[code][1]=BBB222&[codeId][2]=443&[code][2]=ABC123
```

If useful, have a look at the examples using a Param fetcher listener: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.rst

Comment: Unfortunately there is this error: <message>Notice: Array to string conversion</message>

Comment: Which version of FOSRestBundle are you using, can you re-try updating the to the latest stable version?

Comment: I'm using "1.5.*@dev "